# Create interface / type with restricted keys and values

Tags: typescript

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECEEMGMGsFMB2ATUAHATge2vAznqABaQoA2AlogOagAuR8oykdkARpHvAFAiilUGeHQCuGRFVoU6hYXlFlZ9LPUagAZtkR0kqOqtFoWu0DMJ42unj2hZEl0PABuSOgAlBZeBkIBeUABvHlBQIxN4AEldAFs8AC4BPABPRGhQAApoVnhqLAxkxIAiUW4MItAAH1AiugwYWDwigEpQPwA%20IJDQ0H4AEVUTDi4mAEdRHwp8btD%20AGU9MOMc1Bl4OJUnVx0nGJldDFB7UGgSRER4MhruOmj1pu6AXwAabshkZABVMoSk1PSMutIBQyMVLBgpC02p1gj1emABsxWMNuKBxpNpnD%20ABRPZ0UDyRT4gyabS6FAnM4XK4lZa6b4%20B6hF48R42OjJNBMABiZL0AGEqZd-DVwjkGb4KtUijc7nEijwOVyIA0BUKyCKEMksBp6Jz4Dqtm5PORGTZ%20O4sAB3E6kUCRUAxSAINRMLWEQSgZyQMgTQhK-CQDTwAD8fDAABV1O7QHgiFhFKhkJNXKgtFgYq6juwAFbwaD4z0MJje334UkZrMB0AAA159nJyEFpGpeBrPCoBw0MCYUDgEaw9Z0zfOwq6oTFujlvxlImnCtC7y%20P2Kk-gEqZxAoxRiGYqcPhoDm8cToEQWHxVvysFZNkV%20pVcD02O2Hi8Pja49AAG0tWZEI%20CAoCOrYALqJLCPSQBg1C-AACtBkAxCIjIADwBoaLjGu%20vi-vAySge0My7DIA4gZciR9rAA5DnQ5EanhBFPLeNhAA)

I want to create an interface (or type) which keys and values are themselves "typesafe".
For example, I should only be able to set keys which are within an union-type and the same goes for the values.

So I have this:

```
// Backend process handling the database
// and returning its results to the frontend to update its state

const eventHandlers = {
  updateItems: async (category: "user" | "tracks") => {
    // Do database queries
    // Send updated items to event emitter on channel "setItems"
  },
  addUsers: async (email: "string") => {
    // Do database queries
    // Emit result to frontend channel "updateUsers"
  },
}

type FrontendChannels = "updateUsers" | "setItems"
type BackendChannels = keyof typeof eventHandlers

// How can I make the keys and values typesafe?
// The keys should derived from the object and the values from the type `FrontendChannels`
interface BackToFrontChannels {
  updateItems: "setItems"
  addUsers: "updateUsers"
  hi: "mom"      // Should not work
}

type BackendEventHandler = {
  [key in BackendChannels]: {
    args: Parameters<typeof eventHandlers[key]>
    emitToChannel: BackToFrontChannels[key]
  }
}
```

The `BackToFrontChannels` interface is not typesafe and will not warn me very well when my code needs adjustments. How can I fix this?

Comment: *"The `BackToFrontChannels` interface is not typesafe"* - What do you mean?

Comment: @TobiasS. The key `hi` and its value `mom` are both not found in my code. And I can also misspell a key or a value.

Comment: I guess [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY4arm) is as good as it gets. Since you don't specify any relation between the elements in `FrontendChannels` and `BackendChannels`, you will have all options of `BackendChannels` for each key.

Comment: @TobiasS. How did I not think of a mapped type. Yes this works perfectly! (In my example the backend-channels are the keys and the front-end the values though :)
Do you want to write an answer so that I can accept it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can map over the elements inside `BackendChannels`.

```
type BackToFrontChannels = {
  [K in BackendChannels]: FrontendChannels
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=20&pc=1#code/PTAECEEMGMGsFMB2ATUAHATge2vAznqABaQoA2AlogOagAuR8oykdkARpHvAFAiilUGeHQCuGRFVoU6hYXlFlZ9LPUagAZtkR0kqOqtFoWu0DMJ42unj2hZEl0PABuSOgAlBZeBkIBeUABvHlBQIxN4AEldAFs8AC4BPABPRGhQAApoVnhqLAxkxIAiUW4MItAAH1AiugwYWDwigEpQPwA%20IJDQ0H4AEVUTDi4mAEdRHwp8btD%20AGU9MOMc1Bl4OJUnVx0nGJldDFB7UGgSRER4MhruOmj1pu6AXwAabshkZABVMoSk1PSMutIBQyMVLBgpC02p1gj1emABsxWMNuKBxpNpnD%20ABRPZ0UDyRT4gyabS6FAnM4XK4lZa6b4%20B6hF48R42OjJNBMABiZL0AGEqZd-DVwjkGb4KtUijc7nEijwOVyIA0BUKyCKEMksBp6Jz4Dqtm5PORGTZ%20O4sAB3E6kUCRUAxSAINRMLWEQSgZyQMgTQhK-CQDTwAD8fDAABV1O7QHgiFhFKhkJNXKgtFgYq6juwAFbwaD4z0MJje334UkZrMB0AAA159nJyEFpGpeBriv1KrgEaw9Z0zfOwraXVCAG0ANJmRBdhAoAetgC6iT7jfnwtZNg7yqgcD02O2Hi8PmHsNAo61U5napbwqXI56kAw1F%20AAVH5AYiJGQAeAOGlzGkevjnvAyQLu0My7DIPZrqCM49iusF4CBYFPBuNhAA)

Comment: And like this I can also specify "typesafe" relations :D 
`type Validate<T extends {
  [K in BackendChannels]: FrontendChannels
}> = T

type BackToFrontChannels = Validate<{
  updateItems: "setItems"
  addUsers: "updateUsers"
}>`